# ActiveRecord query with has_many :through selecting those that are already in another has_many :through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm sorry for the titlegore but I am not sure how else to describe what I am trying to do. Maybe my explanation will clear it up.

The code:

#### user.rb

```
has_many :user_roles
has_many :roles, through: :user_roles
```

#### category.rb

```
has_many :category_roles
has_many :roles, through: :category_roles
```

What I would like to do now is to create a ActiveRecord relation with which I can select all categories that a given user also posses a relation for. (Basically a user can only access categories he has the given roles for.)

Is there a way to chain this into a where clause? Or is a complete different approach easier? It would have to be as elegant as the one I use right now (except this problem)

Right now I have it solved by getting all categories and filtering them in the ruby side. This is not a big problem as it is only needed at one point and there will only be around 10 categories max so this is something I am willing to sacrifice.

#### For example:

A User has roles `User` and `Admin`.
A Category needs the role `Admin` and `Minecraft`

Then the user should not be allowed to view this given Category, if he had the role `Minecraft` as well then he should be able.